# Unable to access the sample dataset for Google Analytics in BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Goolge very kindly offer a sample dataset of Google Analytics data in BigQuery, so you can run some tests before setting up the actual export to BigQuery.

This is detailed at the following page https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3416091?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089

However when you try to add the project **google.com:analytics-bigquery** as shown in step 5 of the guide. The following error is shown:

> Project IDs may contain letters, numbers, and dashes, with an optional
>   "domain:" prefix.

As you can see the project ID conforms to this, but you are unable to submit the form.

Google is this just a bug?

Does anyone else have the same issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am confirming - just tried and got the same.
Some-when recently - this dialog form was changed (added options to choose from - display in nav vs. make a current project) and looks like the bug was introduced.  previous versions didn't have this bug.

At the same time  - confirming that nothing wrong with project name itself  - with the internal tool that I am using - I was able to add this project successfully

You should report this bug in [BigQuery issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reporting this issue.  We actually already have a fix checked in for this, but we are currently waiting for an opportunity to push this to production, hopefully soon.

In the meantime, you can try one of these workarounds:

- navigate directly to the project: `https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/queries/<project_id>`
- navigate to a dataset on the project, which will display it in the left nav: `https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/dataset/<project_id>:<dataset_id>`